# If you're too Tough to die, do you still burn?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

In Warmachine/Hordes, there are many models which have the 'Tough' rule:

> **TOUGH:**
>   When this model is disabled, roll a d6.  On a 5 or 6, this model heals
>   1 damage point, is no longer disabled, and is knocked down.

There are also attacks which deal the 'Fire' continuous effect:

> **FIRE:**
>   A model hit by this attack suffers the Fire continuous effect, which sets it on fire.  A
>   model on fire suffers a POW 12 damage roll each turn during its controller's Maintenance 
>   Phase until the continuous effect expires.

There are other effects, all subject to the following:

> **CONTINUOUS EFFECTS:**
>   Continuous effects remain on a model and have the potential to damage or affect it in some other way on subsequent turns.  [...] Continuous effects do not require fury points for upkeep and cannot be removed voluntarily.  Remove a continuous effect only when it expires, a special situation causes it to end, or the affected model is removed from the table.

If a model is hit with an attack that would cause it to gain the Fire continuous effect, and that attack kills it, that model is entitled to a 'tough' roll.  If it makes the roll, is it still susceptible to the Fire effect?  Being disabled means it is about to be removed from the table which would cause the effect to expire, but then it survives.  Does the fire go out before the tough roll or does the tough roll prevent the fire from going out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you are reduced to zero hit points, you are `disabled`.  Before you get `boxed` and removed from the table you have to resolve any effects triggered by being `disabled`(I.e. `Tough`).

So during your maintenance phase you roll to see if the fire goes out.  If it doesn't you take the POW 12 damage roll.  If this reduces you to zero hit points, then you are `disabled`.  `Tough` is triggered.  If you pass the `tough` test you are healed back to 1 hit point.  Since your model never left the table, Fire remains In effect.